# How can I fix an overflowed scaled div appearance in IE11 and Edge?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, frontend, scrollbar

I have to create a preview component of an html shown in another html. In the preview section, the content div is scaled down to 0.5 so the users can have an overall idea on how that html will be.

Since the preview section has a fixed width and height, I'm applying an auto overflow in case the content's height is too big.

On every browser works perfect excepting IE11 and Edge, of course. The problem is that on these two browsers an extra double height is added so I'm receiving extra empty content to scroll down.

I noticed that this only happens when the scale is below 1 and I believe that this happens because the initial height is kept, instead of calculating the initial size * scale value.

In the last 48h I haven't managed to find any concrete or working solutions on web for my particular problem (scaled down child of a div with overflow).

PS: this also happens on the width side, but it can be solved with overflow-x: hidden.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<style>
.previewContainer {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.content-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.contentOverflow {
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  color: black;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: scale(0.5);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
</style>
<body>
  <div class="previewContainer">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <div class="contentOverflow">
        <div class="content">
          Lorem Ipsum is siWhat is Lorem Ipsum?
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
          
          Why do we use it?
          It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
          
          
          Where does it come from?
          Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in mply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the 'zoom' property to target IE/Edge, however this is not yet supported in Firefox the equivalent there would be '-moz-transform: scale()'.

I'm guessing you'll then have problems with the width as 'zoom' will want to be 100% wide while 'scale' will want to be 200% wide.

Anyway the following should work for pretty much everything other than Firefox.

```
.content {
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  zoom: 50%;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```